# Specify number of columns in CSS table

Tags: css, primefaces

Is there any way of specifying the number of columns in a table through CSS? For example, I want to create a table dynamically through Java that has 6 columns.
Inline styling is not an option as I am creating the tables dynamically and have to do all styling in CSS classes.

I have this:
[image]

And I want this:
[image]

Or this:

[image]

I have already tried `column-count` and `columns` but they do not work. I can also not use `<col>` since the tables are generated dynamically.

The HTML generated and CSS defined:

```css
.datatable {
  width: 100%;
}
.inner {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  color: purple;
  /* -webkit-column-count: 6; 
    -moz-column-count: 6; 
    column-count: 6 ;
 -webkit-columns: 6; 
    -moz-columns: 6; 
    columns: 6 ; */
}
.inner tr > *:nth-child(1) {
  width: 5%;
}
.inner tr > *:nth-child(2) {
  width: 15%;
}
.inner tr > *:nth-child(3) {
  width: 5%;
}
.inner tr > *:nth-child(4) {
  width: 15%;
}
.inner tr > *:nth-child(5) {
  width: 5%;
}
.inner tr > *:nth-child(6) {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<table class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget datatable" role="grid">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">
        <table class="ui-selectoneradio ui-widget inner">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
                  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                    <input type="radio" value="Y">
                  </div>
                  <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-radiobutton-icon"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label>Yes</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
                  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                    <input type="radio" value="N">
                  </div>
                  <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-radiobutton-icon"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label>No</label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget datatable" role="grid">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">
        <table class="ui-selectoneradio ui-widget inner">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
                  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                    <input type="radio" value="One">
                  </div>
                  <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-radiobutton-icon"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label>One</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
                  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                    <input type="radio" value="Two">
                  </div>
                  <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-radiobutton-icon"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label>Two</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
                  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                    <input type="radio" value="Three">
                  </div>
                  <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-radiobutton-icon"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label>Three</label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
                  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                    <input type="radio" value="Four">
                  </div>
                  <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-radiobutton-icon"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label>Four</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
                  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                    <input type="radio" value="OTHER">
                  </div>
                  <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-radiobutton-icon"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <label>Other</label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Java side:

```
//An idea of the java code flow
PanelGrid indicatorGrid = new PanelGrid();
//Initializing and setting up panelGrid...//
indicatorGrid.setId("...");

//Initializing and setting up component...//
UIComponent component = creator.createControls(indicator);
component.setId(indicator.getIndicatorCode());
//.....//
indicatorGrid.getChildren().add(component);
indicatorGrid.setStyleClass("datatable");
```

Comment: You should post a jsfiddle with your code

Comment: Can you show some relevant "*[mcve]*" snippets of your HTML? @d_z90: a JS Fiddle is a nice bonus - and is incredibly helpful - but is not required, the only requirement is that code to reproduce the problem is posted in the question. As code or as a snippet is down to the choice of the OP. Incidentally, your 'tables' don't look like they're tables, they look more like lists.

Comment: Are these *actual* tables or divs with CSS Table styling?

Comment: I added the code snippets. The tables are generated by primefaces.

Comment: So, your main problem is the padding between the columns right?

Comment: The number of columns. I want to specify the number of columns for all tables. No more, no less.

Comment: I am a bit unclear, What you want is that all the tables you generate, you need equal number of columns?

Comment: Yes, the first line of my question says that. 
See the images I posted. I want the columns of all tables to be equal in number.

Comment: Then simply make sure your panelgrid always gets a multiple of 3 records. So if there are just two, add one 'dummy'

Comment: It works fine for the records more than 3, even if they are not a multiple of 3. Like in the 2nd example table, the record has 5 values, so it automatically makes a 3-columned table.